# How to fix monolithic polypropylene hinges

Tags: repair, hinges, plastic, welding

I have several smaller storage boxes from polypropylene, which were casted as monolith, having their hinges made of thin flexible zones of the same material. They break over the time due to material wear and few rough manipulations. Is there an easy way to fix them? E.g. by welding a thin plastic hair along the hinge. If yes, what are the tools and material?

Example of two monolith PP boxes with flexible hinges:

[image: Example of two monolith PP boxes with flexible hinges.]

A hinge broken after some time:

[image: A hinge broken after some time.]

Side view of a hinge showing its base idea:

[image: Side view of a hinge.]

Comment: Yes, those basically "metal fatigue" their way apart.  IDK if there's a good way to repair, other than *perhaps* some kind of plastic welding.

Comment: If you're really motivated, attach small steel or brass hinges with pop rivets (you may need to bend the leaves to achieve a similar offset for operation clearance). With the rivet head _inside_ they won't interfere with storage space. Otherwise, purchase a high quality drybox of the appropriate size and move on.

Comment: @isherwood – Thank you for an idea and also for your proper understanding that this is more of a generic fixing question of initial design weaknesses than connected to a specific appliance. I primarily needed to understand how to most effectively work with such a polypropylene structure regardless of its placement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, the box for my Omron BP cuff broke at the hinge just like that.

A piece of duct tape has been serving as a new hinge for a couple of years now. It's not elegant but it's cheap, it's quick and it works!